# Static Trait object

Tags: rust, trait-objects

Is it possible to construct a "trait object" without instantiating the struct, IF the trait only contains static methods?

For example:

```
  trait Foo {
    fn bar() -> u8;
    fn baz() -> String;
  }
  
  fn<T: Foo> qux() -> Box<dyn Foo> {
      Box::new(T as Foo)  <--- Compile error
  }
```

I think this should be theoretically possible, since this works:

```
  struct ManualFoo {
    pub bar_fn: fn() -> u8,
    pub baz_fn: fn() -> String
  }

  fn<T: Foo> qux() -> ManualFoo {
    ManualFoo { 
      bar_fn: T::bar,
      baz_fn: T::baz
  }
```

Which kinda is a manually declared trait object, but I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing, or if the compiler actually supports this with some syntax?

Comment: What's the point, associated function (what you call static methods) are not [object safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety), so you either [can't create a trait object](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d5927f58aef8d7c99ea4466b8aed6b6b) at all. Or you opt out with `where Self:Sized` on them and can't call them on a trait object.